# Audio and shutdown issues on Ubuntu 20.04, 21.10

Tags: drivers, nvidia, sound, pulseaudio, shutdown

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H8kgj.jpg)I have a new **Vivobook pro 14X with Ryzen 9 5900HX**, Once I installed Ubuntu(Dual boot with Windows 11) on this everything was fine until the Audio stopped working. At first I tried with Ubuntu 20.04.3 and then 21.10. In each version at after the installation the audio was working for sometimes but then it sopped working.
After the Audio stopped working I also checked in Windows, but it was making some unwanted noise but after the restart it was working fine, but not in Ubuntu.(Once I installed Ubuntu 21.10 this problem resolved)
But **Ubuntu 21.10 is not shutting down**. The system hangs in the session shown in the picture. How can I fix this or is there any alternate versions/distros that I can try.

Comment: If the problem occurs in multiple versions of Linux and also Windows then it's likely a hardware problem. Check all your devices, ports, and cables.

Comment: But in the case of windows audio issue resolved when I updated Ubuntu to 21.10